# How can I retrieve passwords from old keychain after a new install?

Tags: snow-leopard, backup, password, keychain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move items from old keychain to new keychain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61886/move-items-from-old-keychain-to-new-keychain)

Having reinstalled a clean Snow Leopard. Is there a way to access the old keychain - I still have the old time machine backup -  and copy all the wifi account information to my new keychain?

Answer (score 2):

You can copy and paste individual passwords between keychains using Keychain Access. You need, of course, to know the password of the old keychain. Presumably, that is your login password on your previous account.